# Rendering different partials depending on user window size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to test if the user's browser window.width is >= 800px
if so i would like to render partial A otherwise if window.width >= 800px.

I have little experience, please explain my options on implementation:
I am expecting either a javascript method on the page or jQuery.

I have tried

http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/

but 
1. it doesn't work for me. 
2. even if it did I expect it will work based on device being used, not pixel count.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Browser's don't typically let you know the device being used.  The user-agent could get you a fair idea of the OS, but not the specific device.  And even if you had that info, there isn't a standard library to tell you the screen dimensions for each device AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request won't contain data about screen size, so in common sense the sever has no way to know what is screen width and what response to serve, as PinnyM also mentioned in comment.

A general practice is to use User Agent to detect mobile device from server. User Agent is part of request. It's not 100% accurate, but it's something you could still depend on for most cases.

However, there is still solutions for your question - serve page based on screen size.

The workaround is to use Javascript to detect screen size at first, then use JS to drop a cookie. Server is able to read the cookie and decide which template to render.

The basic repo is here: https://github.com/mattstauffer/Simple-RESS It's for PHP, but you can get the idea from the source code.

There is also Rails implementation: https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ress, and the introduction: http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2013/02/15/introducing-ress/

My opinion: I don't like this solution though it is viable. Lots of works to do and lots of things to taking care of. I would rather user User Agent detect instead.

Comment: Thanks for response, will try out and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Ahoy](http://ankane.github.io/ahoy/). The current_visit method contains the following information.

> When someone visits your website, Ahoy creates a visit with lots of
>   useful information.
>
> traffic source - referrer, referring domain, landing page, search
>   keyword location - country, region, and city
>   technology - browser, OS,
>   and device type
>   utm parameters - source, medium, term, content,
>   campaign

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like using a responsive front end framework might be something to look into. I'm a big fan of Foundation, it's super easy to use it with Rails apps. And the new version of Foundation just launched today! Check it out: http://foundation5.zurb.com/